# How To get Old Messages (Chat History) from XMPP

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I am new to XMPP.

and I need to get chat history from **Openfire** with **XMPP**.

I did Googling but didn't get satisfactory Answer.

Any link or idea will be great help.

Comment: Have you implemented in objective C/Swift for getting history

Comment: for the android what i have to do any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to install **Monitoring service** plugin to enable message archiving. You may have to upgrade your openfire service if this plugin is not appearing in your available plugins section in the admin console.

You will need to log into the admin console and go to:
Server --> Archiving --> Archiving Settings to enable message archiving.

Hope this helps you. Feel free to comment in case of any queries/doubts.

Comment: after a long time i am responding on this but i still need to know this... and i am not getting the exact thing from Mark's answer too. so, can you please give me any link or code that is in iOS ? so, i can understand it. thanks for reply...

Comment: You can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657530/how-to-retrieve-chat-history-from-open-fire-in-android/22300454#22300454

Comment: but After enabling ,how to get those archived message back ?

Comment: @Mrug , you can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657530/how-to-retrieve-chat-history-from-open-fire-in-android/22300454#22300454

Comment: @Karun : I have tested above plugin and its working fine, but the problem is its adding that message in database after some delays, SO how to overcome with this delay ?

Comment: @Er.KT I suggest you to check in the Openfire server settings whether there is a setting available to play with this delay value. If there is something like that, making it's value to 0 should help.

Comment: @Karun : I have already checked whole admin panel but there is no any settings available for the same

Comment: @Er.KT In that case, it seems we can't get those messages back as they are not even saved in the server because of that delay.

Comment: Nothing happen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42084375/while-fetching-chat-history-i-am-not-getting-both-user-history-from-openfire

Comment: I have enable this seting and able to see messages in openfire server but how can i get all data from server to my android app

Answer (score 6):

1. You need to enable archiving on the server.
2. Follow http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html to get the messages.

Comment: Should I use this for group chat also?

Comment: This is for Coredata archiving not from getting message from Server Openfire