# how to retrieve the chat history from openfire server?

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I have created a chat application using openfire server and used Smack Api.Its all working fine,now i need to retreive the chat history from openfire server.

I have installed Monitoring Plugin to archive the chat.

[image]

In above screenshot, I can able to see the chat history for both one to one chat and group chat.

Now i need to get the chat history through app programmatically.I have referred many articles and post but did not  find a solution.

If anyone know please tell your suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39271281/chat-history-and-monitoring-plugin-openfire/39429286#39429286).

- If you have installed the monitoring plugin, you can read in its [readme](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/monitoring/readme.html) file under the configuration paragraph the following content:

***Chat archiving is enabled by default. However, only information about who is communicating and at what time is stored unless chat transcript archiving is enabled. To enable chat transcript archiving or group chat archiving, you will need to log into the admin console and go to:***

> Server --> Archiving --> Archiving Settings

- Thereafter the messages get stored in your external database table '**ofMessageArchive**'.
- This history can be further fetched from the database.

Comment: where the  table 'ofMessageArchive' will be..?

Comment: i found the table 'ofMessageArchive' ,now how can i access the table in client side ?

Comment: Did you follow this link to retrieve the history: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39163681/retrieve-history-chat-openfire-xmpp-framework/39236173#39236173

Comment: Hi Sagar Panda, thanks for your reply. I have gone through the link mentioned above.But I don`t  how to use XEP-0136 to archieve history. Can you please give any reference link to achieve this

Answer (score -1):

the XEP (XMPP Extension Protocol) that discuss about this is the [XEP-0313](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html).

[There are some open issues in Openfire backlog to acomplish this XEP.](https://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/OF-1089?jql=text%20~%20%22XEP-0313%22)

So, I suppose that ins't possible yet :(

Good luck!

Comment: In Smack 4.2.0, there will be the `mam` package: https://github.com/Flowdalic/Smack/tree/master/smack-experimental/src/main/java/org/jivesoftware/smackx/mam

Comment: Follow it to retrive chat history from openfire server,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39163681/retrieve-history-chat-openfire-xmpp-framework/39236173#39236173