# How long openfire(XMPP) server maintains user's chat history?

Tags: openfire

I am new to openfire server. I need to know how long openfire(XMPP) server maintains user's chat history ?

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "how much history is stored for a chat room", here is the link for Openfire Admin console where you can configure this settings:

http://[your_server_address]:[admin_port]/muc-history-settings.jsp?mucname=[your_chat_service_name]

[image]

Or perhaps you meant to "Offline messages" received when the user is offline.

http://[your_server_address]:[admin_port]/offline-messages.jsp

[image]

Comment: In addition if you really need user history storing, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20634005/how-to-get-old-messages-chat-history-from-xmpp

Comment: Thank's for your help.